# What is a fix for a constructor definition error?

Tags: c++, oop, constructor, g++

So I have a class:

```
#include "Cool.h"
#include <iostream>

Cool::Cool()
{
    //ctor
}

int getVar()
{
    int pop = 22;
    return pop;
}
```

and a header file:

```
#ifndef COOL_H
#define COOL_H

class Cool
{
    public:
        Cool();
        int getVar();
};
#endif
```

But when I compile, I get an error that says

> error: definition of implicitly-declared 'Cool::Cool()'

EDIT:
Don't know if it will help, but I also have a makefile:

```
program: main.o cool.o
    g++ -o program main.o cool.o

cool.o: Cool.cpp Cool.h
    g++ -c -o cool.o Cool.cpp

main.o: main.cpp cool.o
    g++ main.cpp
```

EDIT 2: Full Error Message:

```
Cool.cpp:4:12: error: definition of implicitly-declared ‘Cool::Cool()’
 Cool::Cool()
            ^
```

Comment: You are missing `Cool::` in front of your `getVar` body.  It should be `int Cool::getVar()`

Comment: The constructor code should work as-is.  In the real code, (1) is the file truly named `Cool.h` (and not `cool.h`; that will matter on some platforms); (2) are the files in the same directory, or are you passing the directory of the header file to the compiler; (3) do you have multiple constructors; and (4) are you using something like default arguments?

Comment: Could you rephrase this as a question?

Comment: Cannot reproduce: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2d2c4f32c7c864a3 (Of course @abelenky is right about `getVar`...)

Comment: The files are in the same directory, the file is Cool.h, and I only have 1 constructor.

Comment: Please post the entire error message (including line numbers) when compiling with `g++ -W -Wall -Wextra -Werror`. In general, if you post an error message, never truncate it, but post the entire thing, because the relevant information may be in the part which you have accidentally truncated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it! I added this to the makefile:

Under main.o:

```
g++ -c -o main.o main.cpp
```

Comment: Also, for purity, you should change `Cool.o` to `Cool.h` to the right from `main.o:`, please see it in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
cool.o: Cool.cpp Cool.h
    g++ Cool.cpp
```

should be:

```
cool.o: Cool.cpp Cool.h
    g++ -c -o cool.o Cool.cpp
```

For `main.o:`:

```
main.o: main.cpp Cool.h
    g++ -c -o main.o main.cpp
```

It is very confusing that you have the same file as both uppercase and lowercase. Does the problem persist after you rename everything to lowercase?

Comment: You haven't updated the `main.o:` part of the `Makefile` yet, which should be updated similarly to `cool.o:` in this answer. Please update it, retry, and post the updated `Makefile`.